# How to delay the Setter to be in affect for 0.5 sec in DataTrigger?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding

I am wondering if it possible to delay a datatrigger to change layout for 0.5 a second. Is any easy way to do it? I need to set the visibility of the object but wait for 0.5 a second.  Any adeas are highly appreciated.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListBoxItemDataTemplate">
        <Grid x:Name="DataItem">
            <Image x:Name="IconImage" Source="{Binding XPath=@icon}" Height="16" Margin="16,0,0,0" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="ListboxIemtextBlock" Text="{Binding XPath=@name}" />
            <Image x:Name="ArrowImage" Height="10" Source="Resources/Images/arrow_collapsed_grey.png" Visibility="{Binding XPath=@state}"/>
        </Grid>
         <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}, Mode=FindAncestor}}" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="ListboxIemtextBlock" Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter TargetName="IconImage" Property="Source" Value="{Binding XPath=@iconSelected}"/>
                <Setter TargetName="IconImage" Property="Height" Value="16"/>
                <Setter TargetName="ArrowImage" Property="Source" Value="Resources/Images/arrow_collapsed_white.png"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}, Mode=FindAncestor}}" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="ListboxIemtextBlock" Property="Foreground" Value="#FF6dacbe"/>
            </DataTrigger>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=SelectedItem.Attributes[retract].Value}" Value="True">      
                <Setter TargetName="ListboxIemtextBlock" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" /> 
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>                     
                    <BeginStoryboard Name="StartAnimation" Storyboard="{StaticResource MakeObjectVisibleAfterHalfASecond}"/>                   
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>                   
                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>                     
                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StartAnimation"/>                   
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>       
            </DataTrigger> 
         </DataTemplate.Triggers></DataTemplate>
```

Storyaboard:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="MakeObjectVisibleAfterHalfASecond" Storyboard.TargetName="ListboxIemtextBlock">         
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Duration="0" BeginTime="0:0:.5">           
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />         
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>       
    </Storyboard>
```

Answer (score 17):

It can be done using an animation.  The pieces involved are:

1) An `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` that sets the `Visibility` property on the target, with a `BeginTime` of `0:0:.5` to delay this for a half second when the storyboard begins.

2) A `DataTrigger` that checks the property whose change will make the object visible (in this case, the `IsChecked` property on the `CheckBox` named `Start`).

3) `BeginStoryboard` in `DataTrigger.EnterActions` that launches the animation, and a `RemoveStoryboard` in `DataTrigger.ExitActions` that makes the object invisible again if the bound property changes back.

Here's a simple working example:

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Page.Resources>
      <Storyboard x:Key="MakeObjectVisibleAfterHalfASecond">
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                       Duration="0"
                                       BeginTime="0:0:.5">
          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
      </Storyboard>
  </Page.Resources>
  <DockPanel>  
    <CheckBox  DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
               Margin="10"
               x:Name="Start">Check this to make the label appear</CheckBox>
    <Border BorderThickness="2" 
            BorderBrush="AliceBlue" 
            CornerRadius="5" 
            Margin="10" 
            Padding="10" 
            DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <Label Visibility="Hidden">
          <Label.Content>This should appear a half second after the box is checked.</Label.Content>
          <Label.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
              <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Start, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                  <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Name="StartAnimation" 
                                     Storyboard="{StaticResource MakeObjectVisibleAfterHalfASecond}"/>
                  </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                  <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StartAnimation"/>
                  </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
          </Label.Style>
        </Label>
    </Border>
    <TextBlock/>
  </DockPanel>
</Page>
```

Note that you could also do this by omitting `BeginTime` and setting `Duration` on the animation, since the two are essentially the same thing with a key-frame animation.

Comment: +1, right! Totally forgot about animation :) That's the way to do it

Comment: It is great way to go in your sample. I am referencing to the sample that Meleak presented and deleted already. My only concern is that you reference to XML attribute 'retract' from code behind which I generate from XMLDataprovider. In my case, I am getting this error in VS-"does not contain a definition for 'retract' and no extension method 'retract' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" it cannot find retract attribute. What can be done? Thank you again.

Comment: Robert, your sample is great. It is easy and reliable. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Robert, when I tried to apply it in my solution I encounter difficulties applying this technique. I am wondering if you can advice. I added a storyboard to the resouces and modified existing datatrigger with Enter and Exit Actions. The application won't run anymore. I am wondering what I do wrong. I added new datatrigger in my question area. Thank you.

Comment: Check the Output window for binding errors at runtime.  There are at least two names misspelled in the modified version you posted; they (and probably more that I didn't notice) are probably the problem.  Also, it's good to just test the DataTrigger to see if it's working at all - make it change some visible property like the `Background` - before messing around with `EnterActions` and `ExitActions`, since if the `DataTrigger` isn't getting tripped, nothing else here will work either.

Comment: Thank you for coming back. I looked into it more carefully. The only spelling I found was in targetname "ListboxItemtextBlock" which I fixed already. I cannot find anything else. I believe the problem is that I cannot reference correctly to the texblock with x:Name="ListboxItemtextBlock" (I corrected it in every instance) when datatrigger is triggered. I am getting errorpointing on the line with the <BeginStoryboard Name="StartAnimation" Storyboard="{StaticResource MakeObjectVisibleAfterHalfASecond}"/> -The error is telling that it cannot find resource named 'MakeObjectVisibleAfterHalfASecond'

Comment: 'MakeObjectVisibleAfterHalfASecond' is spelled corectly. I think that probably referencing in Storyboard with x:Key="MakeObjectVisibleAfterHalfASecond"  to a target - Storyboard.TargetName="ListboxItemtextBlock" can be incorrect in my case. Please advice if it is not an issue. I just think it cannot find the object with TargetName="ListboxItemtextBlock".